# If $p$ is not sum of two squares then $p$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: prime-factorization, gaussian-integers

> Let $p\in \mathbb{N}$ be a prime. Show that if $p$ is not the sum of two squares then $p$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

My approach was to assume $p$ is not a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Then $\exists (s+it), (u+iv)$ such that
$$p=(s+it)(u+iv)=(su-tv)+i(tu+sv).$$

Since $p$ is a natural prime number we have $tu+sv = 0$; therefore, $p=su-tv$.

I want to write $p$ in such way that it's the sum of two squares but I'm unsure how to proceed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Multiply by the conjugate. You get that $p^2=(s^2+t^2)(u^2+v^2)$. Now, since $p$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ each of those factors is $p$. Otherwise one of the two factors you started with would be a unit.

Comment: Great comment. If you make it an anwer I'd gladfully tick it. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate. [It is](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/294706/917479).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which primes $p$ in $Z$ remain primes in $Z[\sqrt{-1}]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294706/which-primes-p-in-z-remain-primes-in-z-sqrt-1)